# Addresses overlapping

Tags: networking, routing, ip

I was putting somes static addresses to my interfaces then it shows me this:

```
172.16.1.0 overlaps with FastEthernet 0/0
```

What does it mean when two addresses overlaps and how can we avoid it?

**EDIT:** The problem happens on the router (on Ubuntu server everything works well)

Comment: What kind of router?  Please display your routing table and interfaces list (`show interfaces brief` and `show ip route` if Cisco)

Answer (score 0):

That most likely means you are trying to add a routing table entry to a network which the router identifies as a local one. In this case it's a network configured on FastEthernet 0/0.